# Is it right to VTC for a Windows-8 tag question to dupe with Windows-8-preview tag?

Tags: discussion, support

I have just seen [Disable charm bar Touchpad shortcut](https://superuser.com/q/511888/86550) with [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) which is somehow similar to [How to disable Windows 8 charm?](https://superuser.com/q/399029/86550) with [windows-8-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview).

So now I'm confused little bit for VTC to it for a dupe? I need your opinion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question (and the posted answers) also apply to Windows 8, re-tag the [windows-8-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview) question with [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) (which I just did) and then vote to close.

If the posted answers are specific to the preview, it's a valid, new question.

Comment: Aha! last line explain it clearly. Thanks.